Module not found: Can't resolve 'swiper/react' vercel error
When I deploy my nextjs project on vercel it gives me this error: -

[09:16:12.919] ./src/app/page.tsx
[09:16:12.920] Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-intersection-observer'
[09:16:12.926] ./src/components/VideoCarousel.tsx
[09:16:12.926] Module not found: Can't resolve 'swiper/react'
[09:16:12.928] ./src/components/VideoCarousel.tsx
[09:16:12.928] Module not found: Can't resolve 'swiper/modules'
[09:16:12.929] ./src/components/VideoCarousel.tsx
[09:16:12.929] Module not found: Can't resolve 'swiper/css'
[09:16:12.930] ./src/components/VideoCarousel.tsx
[09:16:12.930] Module not found: Can't resolve 'swiper/css/pagination'
[09:16:12.933] > Build failed because of webpack errors
[09:16:12.957] Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

enter image description here
My SwiperJS version is
"swiper": "^11.1.9",

This is my VideoCarousel.tsx file :-
'use client';
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import { Swiper as SwiperCore } from 'swiper/types';
import { Pagination, Navigation } from 'swiper/modules';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';

import { CardBody, CardContainer, CardItem } from './ui/3d-card'; // Assuming the paths are correct
import './styles.css';

const VideoCarousel: React.FC = () => {
  const videoRefs = useRef<HTMLVideoElement[]>([]);
  const activeIndexRef = useRef<number>(0);
  const observerRef = useRef<IntersectionObserver | null>(null);

  const handleSlideChange = (swiper: SwiperCore) => {
    const activeIndex = swiper.realIndex;
    activeIndexRef.current = activeIndex;

    videoRefs.current.forEach((video, index) => {
      if (video) {
        if (index === activeIndex) {
          video.play();
          video.muted = false;
        } else {
          video.pause();
          video.muted = true;
        }
      }
    });
  };

  const handleVisibilityChange = () => {
    if (document.hidden) {
      videoRefs.current.forEach((video) => {
        if (video && !video.paused) {
          video.pause();
        }
      });
    } else {
      const activeVideo = videoRefs.current[activeIndexRef.current];
      if (activeVideo) {
        activeVideo.play();
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', handleVisibilityChange);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('visibilitychange', handleVisibilityChange);
    };
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    observerRef.current = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        entries.forEach((entry) => {
          const video = entry.target as HTMLVideoElement;
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            if (videoRefs.current[activeIndexRef.current] === video) {
              video.play();
              video.muted = false;
            }
          } else {
            video.pause();
            video.muted = true;
          }
        });
      },
      {
        threshold: 0.5,
      }
    );

    videoRefs.current.forEach((video) => {
      if (video && observerRef.current) {
        observerRef.current.observe(video);
      }
    });

    return () => {
      if (observerRef.current) {
        videoRefs.current.forEach((video) => {
          if (video && observerRef.current) {
            observerRef.current.unobserve(video);
          }
        });
        observerRef.current.disconnect();
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Swiper
        centeredSlides={true}
        slidesPerView="auto"
        spaceBetween={30}
        loop={true}
        onSlideChange={handleSlideChange}
        modules={[Pagination, Navigation]}
        pagination={{
          dynamicBullets: true,
          clickable: true,
        }}
        navigation
        className="mySwiper custom-swiper-bg"
      >
        {[...Array(6)].map((_, i) => (
          <SwiperSlide key={i} style={{ width: '80%', maxWidth: '400px' }}>
            <CardContainer>
              <CardBody className="bg-gray-50 relative group/card dark:hover:shadow-2xl dark:hover:shadow-emerald-500/[0.1] dark:bg-black dark:border-white/[0.2] border-black/[0.1] w-auto sm:w-[30rem] h-auto rounded-xl p-6 border">
                <CardItem translateZ="100" className="w-full mt-4">
                  <motion.div
                    initial={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.9 }}
                    animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
                    exit={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0.9 }}
                    transition={{ opacity: { duration: 0.5 }, scale: { duration: 0.5 } }}
                    className="w-full h-96 rounded-lg shadow-lg video"
                  >
                    <video
                      ref={(el) => {
                        if (el) {
                          videoRefs.current[i] = el;
                        }
                      }}
                      className="w-full h-full rounded-lg"
                      controls={false}
                      controlsList="nodownload noremoteplayback"
                    >
                      <source src={`/reel${i + 1}.mp4`} type="video/mp4" />
                      Your browser does not support the video tag.
                    </video>
                  </motion.div>
                </CardItem>
              </CardBody>
            </CardContainer>
          </SwiperSlide>
        ))}
      </Swiper>
    </>
  );
};

export default VideoCarousel;

I have tried setting my .gitconfig ignorecase=true, I have read the docs of SwiperJS but still this problem remains unsolved.
